# Proving that $p(x)=x^4-2cx^2+x+c^2-c$ has a root if $c>1$, and no root if $c<3/4$

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Prove that if $c > 1$ then the polynomial $$p(x) = x^{4} - 2cx^{2} + x + c^{2} - c$$ has a real root, and if $c < \frac{3}{4}$ it has no real roots.

- For the first part, it suffices to find a point $a$ such that $p(a) \leqslant 0$ since $p(0) = c^{2} - c > 0$, but I don't know what such point is.
- For the second part, my idea is to use proof by contradiction but I don't know how to proceed.

Can you give me some hints? Thanks.

Comment: "Proof by induction"? Inducting on what? Besides, I take it you are aware of the intermediate value theorem, right? (The one which is used to prove that if there is $a$ with $p(a) \leq 0$ and $p(0)>0$ then there's a root between $a$ and $c$.) That will probably be required for this question, along with some estimates.

Comment: @ Teresa Lisbon Yes. I'm aware of the theorem. I also edited the question.

Comment: Huh?  $p$ has roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What about $\frac{3}{4} < c < 1$?

Comment: @soupless It has root in that case.

Comment: @user10354138 How did you find out?

Comment: If so, I think you should change $c > 1$ to $c > \frac{3}{4}$. Also, @user10354138 is referring to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Comment: @soupless Since I knew it and the proof was different, I didn't write it that way. But you are right.

Comment: @soupless I also know the fundamental theorem of algebra but how is it said that the roots are imaginary for sure?

Comment: Not imaginary, complex. It is always guaranteed for any polynomial. However, there are cases where the imaginary part of a complex root is zero, hence, a real root.

Comment: @soupless I know it. But how do we want to use it here? what conclusion do we want to get from it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124215/discussion-between-soupless-and-emad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Note that $x^4 - 2cx^2 + x + c^2 - c = (x^2+x-c) (x^2 -x + 1-c)$. Consider the discriminant of the factors.

Bottom line: $x^4 - 2cx^2 + x + c^2 - c$ has real roots iff $c\ge -1/4$.

Comment: Excellent. Factoring the polynomial hadn't struck my mind.

Comment: I asked [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E4+-+2cx%5E2+%2B+x+%2B+c%5E2+-+c+).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is erroneous. For $c=0$ we have, in fact, $2$ real roots(I assume that is what you want).

Comment: Yes. I understood it has problems. But how should we change it?

Comment: Well, for one thing, in the interval $0<c<1$ we would always have a root, a positive root in fact, from Descartes' rule of signs.

Comment: That's right. I got it.